# performance, internal working and order of execution of serial steam

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I donot believe that streams have been added just to add more readability to the code by gimmicking the functional programming.

If I have multiple operations being performed on stream, how are they computed internally.

1. How are map functions computed in case of multiple map function application. one element at a time or one map operation on full stream followed by another.
2. How is it any different from normal iterations performed on collection in respect of performance.
3. When talking about non-parallel stream, is the order of computation of elements depends only on the type of input collection (i,e ordered for list, linkedHashmap , sortedset and unordered for hashSet, etc).
4. Can I get some more insights on the internal working of streams so as to decide better on when are streams not advised to use and when are they advised to be used.(factors to check on 
   like collection size, nature of sequence, etc, )
5. I know byte code is created for every class in form of .class. How is bytecode created for all the lambda functions used internally in the streams operation.

---

```
    List<Integer> ee = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f1 = x -> x * 2;
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f2 = x -> x * x;
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f3 = x -> x / 2;

    ee.stream().map(f1).map(f2).map(f3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Current Stream API implementation processes elements one-by-one without intermediate buffering, unless it has to. For sequential stream only `sorted()` operation is a "full barrier" operation, so for `map(f1).sorted().map(f2)` the `f1` will be applied for the whole stream, then the result will be sorted and `f2` will be applied to the every resulting item. In other cases including adjacent `map(f1).map(f2)` the `f1` and `f2` functions will be applied both for the first element, then both for the second element, and so on.
2. Could be faster or could be slower, heavily depends on many things including which operations are you using, which collection is your stream source, how many input elements you have, how you collect the result.
3. In current implementation - yes. Though it's not specified. The specification requires most of the functions used throughout the stream (e.g. function passed to `map`) to be [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness), so if your program behavior depends on lambdas execution order, it's likely that you violate the specified contract.
4. The most important factor is code clarity. If using the stream API makes code easier to read, it's likely ok to use it. If you clearly see that your Stream is a performance bottleneck you may try to get rid of it. However, this rarely happens in practice. I tend to avoid creating many very short streams as they produce garbage, so many short streams mean much garbage per processed element. However, this also not always matters in practice.
5. Lambdas are compiled to separate synthetic methods inside your class body and expanded at runtime to anonymous classes implementing the corresponding functional interface and calling that synthetic method. This is done using `invokedynamic` bytecode instruction and bootstrap factory (see `java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory` class in the standard library). If your lambda does not capture anything, the runtime representation will be a singleton. Otherwise, a new instance of that anonymous class will be created every time.

Comment: thankyou @TagirValeev. I woulf like to know more details about the point4 in my question. "Can I get some more insights on the internal working of streams so as to decide better on when are streams not advised to use and when are they advised to be used.(factors to check on like collection size, nature of sequence, etc, )". It would be the most helpful point to identify the scenarios.